# Debug on iOS device with newer release than Base SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, version

I have a bug (UI unresponsive) on an app that is built with iOS12 SDK.  The bug does not appear if built with iOS13 SDK (but to do this this requires lots of other destabilising changes).  I would like to just patch the iOS12SDK build for now until our iOS13SDK build is ready for release.

The problem being is I can't run the debugger on an iOS13.x device on xcode 10.3 to find out what the problem actually is!

It used to be that you can set the Base SDK in xcode to previous versions.  There is still a Base SDK option which is set to iphoneos (possible to also use iphoneos13.1), and I have tried `ln -s`'ing my xcode 10.3 iphoneos12.4.sdk into the xcode 11.1 platforms directory, but xcode does not find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste iOS13.x Device Support to the below location.

`Xcode app > Show package contet > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport`

You can download device support from here :
https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: So in my case added to the Xcode10.3.app directory.  Bug fixed, lovely, thanks!